# Await keyword can't be used in the following code. I couldn't find out why

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api2

Why can't I use await in this below block?

VS throws compile error if I use await keyword in the following code.

```
[ResponseType(typeof (ApiTableDetailDto))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetApiTable(int id)
    {
        var apiTable = await Mapper.Map<ApiTableDetailDto>(_unitOfWork.ApiTableRepository.GetById(id));
        if (apiTable == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(apiTable);
    }
```

Please do advise.

Comment: I'm sure you mean C# 5.0. What version of .NET is this?

Comment: Is Mapper Automapper?  If so Map is not an async method.  You can only await an async method that returns a Task or Task<T>.

Comment: @shf301 Thanks. It's automapper.  it's C#5.0

Answer (score 0):

Well the question has actually been answered by @shf301, but I thought I'd  throw in an example on how you can await in this case.

If the `_unitOfWork` have Async methods then you can do it like this:

```cs
var response = await _unitOfWork.ApiTableRepository.GetByIdAsync(id);
var apiTable = Mapper.Map<ApiTableDetailDto>(response);
```